# MSACCESS Function Name Error (Spanish/English)

Tags: function, vba, ms-access

This looks more like a configuration problem than a coding problem, but I just can't seem to find the source or solution.

I develop in an English enviroment, while working in my Reports the functions have English names, aka "Right", "Left", "Date". But it looks like when I deploy on some of the clients computers the language the client-pc understands is "Spanish", so it want's the functions names to be "Derecha", "Izquierda", "Fecha". And as such, fails to understand the functions I wrote.

Curious thing is, on the VBA code, this doesn't matter, it's only when I use the functions as a value on a property like "ControlSource". Eg.: `Format(DocNum, "0000")` Will work perfectly on my dev-pc, but return #Name? on the client's

Any ideas as to how to solve this (besides asking them to re-install)

Comment: The function names depend on the language of the user interface. In Windows, this can be changed in Regional & Language Options or something similar. Set the language of the Dialogs to English to get English function names. However, the names should be translated automatically. At least that works in Excel...

Comment: @MP24 Yeah, tried that, to no avail. This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If VBA modules you created in English work fine on the client machine try creating functions that recreate the left, right, date etc functions like this:

```
Public Function AltLeft(str As String, l As Long)
    AltLeft = Left(str, l)
End Function
```

and use the alternate functions in your properties.

Comment: This is a clever idea. But it seems better to solve the configuration problem (which is very mysterious). Otherwise I see future weirdness ahead. Also this answer might cause slow query processing.

Comment: That's a patch that works I have had to do it for a couple functions. But I can't be creating a function for every function that access has that I could need. I would much rather find the core of the problem and solve it. But thanks.